# Enable Disable some component using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some values in my viewbag.I access that viewbag contents using Jquery.Initially my controllers are disabled.But according to viewbag rules i need to enable some some components.

> > Problem is thisone not enabled according to viewbag values.always show it disabled mode.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.txtnews').attr("disabled", "disabled") //Initially disabled
    $('.txthq').attr("disabled", "disabled")

    if ('@ViewBag.NewsMode'.indexOf("Show")) { // accroding to viewbag values,need thisone enabled.
        $('.txtnews').attr("enabled", "enabled")
    }
    if ('@ViewBag.NewsMode'.indexOf("hqm")) {
        $('.txthq').attr("enabled", "enabled")
    }

})
 </script>
```

Comment: you can try $('.txtnews').attr('disabled', false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure `enabled` is a valid attribute, perhaps you just want to remove the disabled attribute instead? For this you can use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

For example:

```
if ('@ViewBag.NewsMode'.indexOf("Show") != -1) {
    $('.txtnews').removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s4jpurev/)

---

Alternatively you could tidy up your logic and only apply disabled when needed. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@ViewBag.NewsMode'.indexOf("Show") == -1) {
        $('.txtnews').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    if ('@ViewBag.NewsMode'.indexOf("hqm") == -1) {
        $('.txthq').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
})
```

Comment: @TechGuy: Just a point, if `NewsMode` **starts** with "Show" then `indexOf` will be 0 (which is false). Instead you could do `>= 0` or `!= -1` to check if it contains it